# Amount based Sorting

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have two values, an address and amount in a game. In each round the user makes his contribution. The users address and the total contribution is sent to a function which maintains a list of players in a sorted manner.

There is a function that rewards the top players and resets the list. What would be the best approach to maintain the list of players and be able to reset it in a round independent manner.

Comment: It would help if you post the code that you have currently.

Comment: With that said it is often not a good idea to sort on chain(Using the EVM).  Typically it is more cost effective to sort off chain.  If I am understanding your example properly I would solve it by creating an array(public) of all addresses and a mapping of address => contribution.  Then off chain I would call to get the value of the array then for each entry, get the contribution and sort accordingly.  Hope this helps.